# System policies prevent QGIS installation - false alarm?

Tags: qgis, installation

I get the following message during install Quantum GIS 1.8.0-Lisboa on Windows 7:

[image]

I tried doing the install as administrator with the same result. The install finishes after the 'ok' button is clicked and QGIS seems to be functioning after the install.

What is causing the installer popup and how do I fix it? Or should I leave as it is?

Comment: Maybe user account control issue? If qgis does work, dont spend too much energy on it

Comment: If your computer is joined to a domain then the Domain Administrator might have set those policies. If not just google the message text for info on how to fix it.